# name 'QString' is not defined

Tags: pyqgis

QGIS V-3.4.5, Python 3.7.0

```
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.core import *

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)

from PyQt5.QtCore import * # QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication

from PyQt5.QtGui import * #QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * #QAction

from PyQt5.QtXml import QDomDocument

import os.path
import os

...

 actionSelect = QAction( QString("Select"), self)

             NameError: name 'QString' is not defined
```

**NameError: name 'QString' is not defined**

WHY???

Comment: what is that `sip.setapi` line supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for it - just use a python 3 string.

See for example discussion on the internet such as: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/PyQt5-and-QString-td5043297.html

```
 actionSelect = QAction("Select", self)
```

I suppose if you are converting a bunch of code that uses `QString()` you could define:

```
def QString(x):
  return x
```

and remove any imports of Qt's QString.

Comment: Thanks!
Works as 

actionSelect = QAction("Select")